# java implementation of the linear search on a sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, linear-search

I'm trying to implement a java code to test linear search on a sorted array and this is my code

```
public class ArrayTest {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int []x= {12,8,6,23,6,5,17,20,9};
    int y  =linearSearch(x,23);
}
public static  int linearSearch(int []ar,int value) {
    int searchedIndex=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
        if (ar[i]==value) {
            searchedIndex=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return searchedIndex ;
}

}
```

The problem is that this doesn't generate any output also no errors were generated. Can anyone explain the reason for this.

Comment: `System.out.println ("The index is " + y);`

Comment: Your array **isn't** sorted.

Comment: You are not printing anything! Use *System.out.println()* function to print your result.

Comment: Your problems stem from misunderstanding of Java at its most basic and suggests that you should review your notes/book/tutorials. You can find the tutorials here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat

Comment: @ElliottFrisch true it is not sorted. Is there is a way to sort it instead of using Array.sort. If there is please explain

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks ill review quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {12, 8, 6, 23, 6, 5, 17, 20, 9};
//      Arrays.sort(x);
        int y = linearSearch(x, 23);
        System.out.println("" + y);
//      int z = Arrays.binarySearch(x, 23);
//      System.out.println("" + z);
    }

    public static int linearSearch(int[] ar, int value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (ar[i] == value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Note the commented out lines are for if you actually wanted a sorted array instead of an unsorted array

Answer (score 1):

In order to print something to the output,you must use System.out.println() function.The answer is returned to the variable y.Just print the variable to the console output.Moreover,the array is not sorted.But,that doesn't make any problem to it.